# Application of Lagrange's theorem

Tags: number-theory

I've attempted the following question. I've made some headway with part i) as I've seen similar before but I'm unsure how to finish it and I've started part ii) but once again I'm not sure how to finish it. I'd appreciate it if someone could check I'm on the right lines and advise  what to do next.

Let $p$ be a prime and $d$ a positive factor of $p−1$. Let $R=${$1,..., p−1$} and $S=${$x^d| x ∈ R$ }.

We consider two members of S to be equal if they are congruent modulo p.

(i) Prove that $y^{(p−1)/d} ≡ 1 $mod $p$ for all $y ∈ S$ and apply Lagrange’s Theorem to deduce
that $|S| ≤ (p−1)/d$.

For i) we have $p$ is prime, $d>0$ and $d|p-1$. Suppose $y∈\mathbb{Z}$ with $y \not\equiv 0$ mod $p$. Then $(y^{\frac{p−1}{d}})^d ≡ y^{(p-1)}$ $≡ 1$ mod $p$ by Fermat. Therefore $y^{(p−1)/d}$ is a solution to $x^d ≡ 1$ mod $p$. This is at most $d$ solutions by Lagrange, therefore $y^{(p-1)/d}$ takes at most $d$ values.

(ii) Prove that $|S| = (p−1)/d$.

For each $s ∈ S$ I need to consider the set $R_s =$ { $x ∈ R | x^d ≡ s$ mod $p$} and apply Lagrange’s Theorem.

Comment: What is $x$? $ $

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I think $x$ belongs to the set of roots of a polynomial modulo a prime which has been called $R$ in this question.

Comment: Isn't $R$ just the integers $1$ through $p-1$? edit: $R$ is the set of all possible remainders modulo $p$, right?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Ah, yes you're correct.

Comment: So is $x$ any element of $R$? I'm confused :(